# Number of linear maps is less or equal than the dimension of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

### Problem

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. Let $T_1,T_2,\dots,T_m$ be linear maps $V\rightarrow V$ such that $\dim R(T^{2}_{i})=\dim R(T_i)=1$ for all $i=1,2,\dots,m$, and $T_i\circ T_j$ is the zero map for all $i \neq j$. Prove that $m\leq n$.

---

### Thoughts

If I choose $v_i\in R(T_i),~v_i\neq 0~\forall~i=1,2,\dots,m$ and show that $T_i(v_i)=a_iv_i$ for some $a_i\neq 0$ and $T_i(v_j)=0~\forall~i\neq j$ . . .

Comment: @YACP Oh, no. I am a very busy person. Honors, clubs, all that. I didn't have time. I'm sorry. I do appreciate your effort. Thank you.

Comment: Don't do too much! ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to introduce orthogonality (which doesn't even make sense without an inner product).

Since $\dim R(T_i)=1$, there exists $m$ basis vectors $v_i \in R(T_i) \subseteq V$ for the respective ranges, i.e. $v_i$ is a basis of $R(T_i)$. Put $v_i = T_i(w_i)$. I affirm that these vectors are all linearly independent. If they were not, say with a linear dependence relation $a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_m v_m = 0$ with $a_i \neq 0$, then applying $T_i$ gives $$0 = a_1 T_i(v_1) + \ldots + a_m T_i(v_m) = a_1 T_i(T_1(w_1)) + \ldots + a_m T_i(T_m(w_m)) = a_i T_i(v_i).$$

Since $a_i \neq 0$, we must have $T_i(v_i) = 0$, which implies that $R(T_i^2)=\{0\}$, a contradiction. Thus we have $m$ linearly independent vectors in a $n$-dimensional space; hence we must have $m \leq n$.

Comment: Well done. You are right we don't need an inner product.

Comment: @AlexP. Here here!

Comment: @RossMillikan What is $w_i$ here?

Comment: @YosefQian It's a vector in $V$ such that $T(w_i) = v_i$.

Answer (score 2):

To have $\dim R(T^{2}_{i})=\dim R(T_i)=1$, each $T_i$ must map the whole space to a line and in fact map vectors along that line to that line (with a scaling factor allowed) and all vectors perpendicular to the line to $\vec 0$.  Then the condition $T_i \circ T_j= 0$ forces the lines to be perpendicular.  For if the line $T_j$ maps to is not perpendicular to the one $T_i$ maps to, the output vector of $T_j$ will have a component along the line $T_i$ maps to and the result will not be zero.  The figure below shows what happens in $\Bbb R^2$ if the two axes are not perpendicular.  As there are only $n$ perpendicular directions in $\Bbb R^n$ your are there.[image]

Comment: Is there a more "general" "picture" for dimensions for some arbitrary $n$?

Comment: @Trancot:   The same will apply.  I just can't draw it as well.  You still need all the lines to be perpendicular.

Comment: There's no notion of orthogonality in a general vector space.

Comment: @Alex P. Projections are orthogonal if their composition is the zero map are they not?

Comment: @ScottH. (1) We're not necessarily dealing with projections.
(2) What does *orthogonal* mean in a general vector space?

Comment: @Alex P.  (1) you're right, I just saw $T^2$ and $T$ and thought idempotent.  For your second point I've just seen that as defining orthogonality of projections.  I guess that is what it would mean, but I don't know whether it corresponds exactly to the idea of orthogonality wrt inner product so I asked.

Comment: @ScottH. It is only meaningful to speak of orthogonality with respect to an inner product. In a general vector space, we can always talk about projections, but not necessarily *orthogonal* projections.

Comment: @AlexP. I got it now, the definition I was referring to (Roman p(75)) was defining orthogonality between pairs of _maps_ not as a projection which is orthogonal.

Comment: @ScottH. Interesting. I've never heard about this notion.